# What does it mean for a phase portrait to have "limit cycle behavior?"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system:

$dx/dt = x(1-x)-\frac{kxy}{kx+1}$

$dy/dt = ry(1-\frac{y}{x})$

For values of r as 0.15, 0.11, and 0.05, which of the corresponding phase portraits displays limit cycle behavior?  Is the cycle an attractor or a repeller?

I found the three portraits as:

r = 0.15

[image]

r = 0.11

[image]

r = 0.05

[image]

But I don't know how to tell which one exhibits "limit cycle behavior."  Can anyone explain what this means and how I can know, by looking at each phase portrait, which is the correct answer (and whether it's a repeller or attractor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a limit cycle, In the limit as $t \to \infty$, the response tends to some cycle (e.g., some curve parameterizable by some periodic form).

In your first plot, the curve keeps spiralling inward. In your second, it sticks to a "race track" pattern. The second is a limit cycle oscillation.

Comment: Great, succinct explanation.  Thanks for the help.